# Mysql Recurring Events

Tags: mysql, events

I am trying to update my table after every 24 hours. I have tried the following examples but event triggers only one time

```
CREATE EVENT mydb.time_sync
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY '1 0' DAY_HOUR       
STARTS '2013-01-16 16:53:00' 
DO
  UPDATE mydb.mytable SET is_time_sync = 0;
```

I tried another but it again repeats only one time

```
CREATE EVENT mydb.time_sync2
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 24 DAY_HOUR       
DO
  UPDATE mydb.mytable SET is_time_sync = 0;
```

this failed too occur just one time

```
CREATE EVENT mydb.time_sync3
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' DAY
STARTS '2013-01-16 16:53:00' 
DO
    UPDATE mydb.mytable SET is_time_sync = 0;
```

I am using MySQL 5.5 and event scheduler is ON

Comment: i have checked next day after 16:53 , even checked after 5 days but it didn't fired...
More, i changed my system time according to  and again it didn't triggered but only once....

Comment: @eggyal the date i used in was '2013-01-16 16:53:00' not '2013-01-21 16:53:00'

Comment: Can you see the event scheduler in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`?  Do you see any relevant errors in your server's error log?  You could try [`mysqladmin debug`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqladmin.html).

Comment: Yes,It shows(But DB is null don't know why)
<br>
Id  User  Host          db     Command  Time  State  Info
<br>
1151 event_scheduler localhost  NULL Daemon  87145  Waiting for next activation  NULL

Answer (score 0):

The query for the event you are writing is alright, but there is one thing you are missing. You have not enabled the event scheduler that causes it to execute the trigger only once.

To you enable that you have to write `event_scheduler=on` somewhere under the `[mysqld]` section in the default MySQL config file, usually /etc/my.cnf or my.ini